# set Exampleset to ExampleSet2SimilarityExampleSet Rapidminer Operator with java

Tags: java, machine-learning, data-mining, rapidminer

I create a process that measure similarity. I use ExampleSet2SimilarityExampleSetoperator and I want to add in input an example set which generated in my code.

The first idea is to write my example set in local repository. Then I will use retrieve operator to read example set and connect the output of operator retrieve to input of operator ExampleSet2SimilarityExampleSet.

So I wonder if I can avoid read/write.

```
  public class Test {

        public static void main(String[] args) throws OperatorCreationException, OperatorException{
            Test t = new Test();        
            t.createprocess();
        }
          public void createprocess() throws OperatorCreationException, OperatorException{
                RapidMiner.init();
                ExampleSet exampleset = getExampleset();

                Operator silimarityOperator = OperatorService.createOperator(ExampleSet2SimilarityExampleSet.class);
        //        silimarityOperator.setParameter("measure_type", "NumericalMeasures");
        //        silimarityOperator.setParameter("numerical_measure", "CosineSimilarity");

                Process process = new Process();
                process.getRootOperator().getSubprocess(0).addOperator(silimarityOperator);
                process.getRootOperator().getSubprocess(0).getInnerSources().getPortByIndex(0).connectTo( silimarityOperator.getInputPorts().getPortByName("input"));

                // run the process with new IOContainer using the created exampleSet
                IOContainer run = process.run(new IOContainer(exampleset));
                System.out.println(run.toString());




            }

            public ExampleSet getExampleset() {
        // construct attribute set
                Attribute[] attributes = new Attribute[3];
                attributes[0] = AttributeFactory.createAttribute("Topic1", Ontology.STRING);
                attributes[1] = AttributeFactory.createAttribute("Topic2", Ontology.STRING);
                attributes[2] = AttributeFactory.createAttribute("Topic3", Ontology.STRING);

                MemoryExampleTable table = new MemoryExampleTable(attributes);
                DataRowFactory ROW_FACTORY = new DataRowFactory(0);

                Double[] strings = new Double[3];

                double a = 0;
                for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                    a++;
                    strings[i] = a;
                    // make and add row
                    DataRow row = ROW_FACTORY.create(strings, attributes);

                    table.addDataRow(row);
                }

                ExampleSet exampleSet = table.createExampleSet();
                return exampleSet;
            }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution. I have error at connection of operator. It is not exist port input, so I get port 0.

```
 process.getRootOperator().getSubprocess(0).getInnerSources().getPortByIndex(0).connectTo(  
          silimarityOperator.getInputPorts().getPortByIndex(0));

     silimarityOperator.getOutputPorts().getPortByIndex(0).connectTo(
          process.getRootOperator().getSubprocess(0).getInnerSinks().getPortByIndex(0));
```